# Advice on computing walked distance in web-app

Tags: web-applications, geolocation, polymer, mapbox, visibility

I'm currently building an web-app (in Polymer using Mapbox) where users can see featured routes on a map and walk them. They asked me if it would be possible to add a button (start/stop) to record their activity and calculate the number of kilometers walked. The way I would build this is to store each new geopoint on a location change event (`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`) and calculate the distance between all points and sum those.

**Now the real problem**

There will probably be users that forget to click the stop button again. If this happens the application will keep on sending data to my server. This will result in unnecessary data being pushed to the database.

Now I tried to find a solution for this:

**Option #1**

I came across the option to check the active tab in the browser making use of the [Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/). In this way I could automatically stop/start tracking.

```
if (!document.hidden) {
    // resume tracking
} else {
    // stop tracking
}
```

However, usually the users of my app will lock their screens which will also stop tracking because `visibilityState` will be `hidden`.

**Option #2**
My client came with the solution to automatically stop the timer after x hours. However, this doesn't sound intuitive because this will still result into a strange sum of kilometers.

**Option #3**
Automatically stop tracking walked distance if you're more than x meters away from a featured route. This however will require quite some computation.

**Option #4**
Track all user activity. E.g. pinching, clicking, zooming etc on the map and stop tracking after 30 minutes of no activity

How should I design this app to make sure that the tracking makes sense?

Comment: Use ionic to make native like webapp. Only with a framework like this you will be able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are facing the same problem as I do here is the workaround I came up with.

I used [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com) to play a video in the background to make sure that the mobile doesn't go in full sleep mode. Make sure to only add NoSleep if the user has interaction with your app, otherwise it'll only drain the battery.

```
var noSleep = new NoSleep();
document.addEventListener('click', enableNoSleep, false);

function enableNoSleep() {
  noSleep.enable();
  document.removeEventListener('click', enableNoSleep, false);
}
```

And also make sure to disable it using `noSleep.disable();`

Everytime my app (active tab in Chrome using the [Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/)) comes active again I poll the current location.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible") this.getCurrentLocation();
});
```

The `getCurrentLocation()` location will push the current location in an `Array` called `locationHistory`.

I'm using [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) to calculate the distance between the previous location and the current location in the `locationHistory` array.

```
let currentLocation = turf.point(lastpoint);
let previousLocation = turf.point(previouspoint);
let distance = turf.distance(previousLocation, currentLocation);
```

I will take the distance between current location and previous location and add it to my `totalDistance`.

If the user has the app in his pocket and comes back "online" (opens the app) it'll take the distance between current location and previous location. It's not super accurate (because it'll only take straight lines between two points( but I did some tests and this is the best I can do for a web app. The result will be more accurate if the user prevent the phone from going in locked mode.

When you hit start I create a timestamp on the server ([Firebase Server Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue)) so I know when the user starts tracking. I also know that the longest route in the system is approximately 11km, which means this should be walkable in 3hrs.

I'm running some Firebase Cloud Functions to see if users are still tracking after 3hrs and will disable tracking on the server. When the user opens the app after a few days it stopped tracking client side.

If you found a better solution, please let me know! I'm curious ;-)